# Seeing same review item twice

Tags: discussion, review

Often, there are only one or two items in the First Posts and Late Answers review queues. I open one queue, go through both items, and then go to the other queue. I am then confronted with the same answer I just reviewed. Is this intentional, or not often enough to matter, or a bug?

Comment: Can you give an example? I mean what are the two queues that have the same question for review? It seems reasonable that, say for example, a  an answer can be flagged as both a First Post and a Late Answer.

Comment: @Code-Guru those two + Low Quality Posts often seen on AskDifferent